# Piping lines to repeat commands

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep, pipe

If my grep operation returns a list of IDs like in the following, can I somehow feed/pipe each line to a commandline command's parameter?:

```
12345
84758
49549
..
```

Like for example with the above result from grep, I'd like to call with [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL).

```
curl http://example.org/activate/12345
curl http://example.org/activate/84758
curl http://example.org/activate/49549
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out:

```
egrep -o "[0-9]{5}" | while read -r line ; do curl http://mydomain.com/activate/$line ; done
```